# Fixed header, useful or not?

Tags: website-design

I'm making a website now, and to be honest I'm not really a designer. Currently the site I'm making does not have a fixed header, and I'm not currently sure if I should make it fixed or not. A lot of sites I use do not have a fixed header, but I see the potential and use of it.

**My question:** What do you think of fixed headers? Does it make the website easier to use, or do you think it's waisted pixels? Or do you think a fixed header is a great option for a site when the screen is only x pixels width?

Comment: The question seems a bid broad and honestly is probably better suited for ux.stackexchange. In fact they have a number of similar questions on their site there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general answer for this. It really depends on the type of the website its size, audience and the amount of information you want to "stick".

If the users will need to often switch between the pages or access some links from the menu it may be worth doing that. May be very useful for web applications  where constant access to some tools will be crucial.

Simple marketing pages on the other hand may be better off with properly planed information and strategically placed links within content itself, suggestively leading the visitors through product discovery.

Website is never done, you should try and measure your approaches. Do A/B testing etc.